# Get the project of the current editing file

Tags: visual-studio-extensions, vsx

I created my first VS extension following [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/walkthrough-displaying-light-bulb-suggestions?view=vs-2019).

I would like to the get the project of the current editing file, i.e. related project properties from `ITextView textView` and `ITextBuffer textBuffer`.

After some searching, I have found:

1. [get the file path from ITextView](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0f6ef03a-df6b-4670-856e-f4a539fbfbe1/how-get-document-name-of-an-iwpftextview?forum=vseditor)
2. [get all project properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/getting-project-properties?view=vs-2019)

It seems that I could match file path against all projects to decide this, but it is not ideal.

Could I get this information directly somewhere?

Comment: Have you solved this? Currently looking for a solution without iterating all projects.

Answer (score 0):

Hey :) I had the same question last week.

The current open filename:

```
DTE dte = Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(SDTE)) as DTE;
        string docName = dte.ActiveDocument.Name;
```

I used ITagger - it's called every time something is changed in your code, so you are always up-to-date. Have a look at this [tutorial](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/visualstudio-docs/blob/master/docs/extensibility/walkthrough-creating-a-margin-glyph.md).

```
IEnumerable<ITagSpan<IssueTag>> ITagger<IssueTag>.GetTags(NormalizedSnapshotSpanCollection spans)
    {
        DTE dte = Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(SDTE)) as DTE;
        string docName = dte.ActiveDocument.Name;

        foreach (SnapshotSpan span in spans)
        {
            //look at each classification span \
            foreach (ClassificationSpan classification in m_classifier.GetClassificationSpans(span))
            {
                //if the classification is a comment
                if (classification.ClassificationType.Classification.ToLower().Contains("comment"))
                {
                    //if the word "todo" is in the comment,
                    //create a new TodoTag TagSpan
                    int index = classification.Span.GetText().ToLower().IndexOf(m_searchText);
                    if (index != -1)
                    {
                        yield return new TagSpan<IssueTag>(new SnapshotSpan(classification.Span.Start + index, m_searchText.Length), new IssueTag());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```